# magento 2 stop checkout processing

Tags: magento2, checkout, mixins

I have this problem in magento 2 checkout.
I want that after a check in the billing address fields, if there is an error it stop checkout processing and not go to the success page.

How can I stop checkout processing in mixins?

file: **set-billing-address-mixins.js**

Here the code:

```
alert($t("Insert SDI field to have elettronic invoice!"));
$('div[name="shippingAddress.custom_attributes.sdi"] input').focus();
return false
```

**return false** doesn't work.

Have you any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
], function ($, $t, quote, errorProcessor) {
    'use strict';

    return function () {
        try {
            alert($t("Insert SDI field to have elettronic invoice!"));
            $('div[name="shippingAddress.custom_attributes.sdi"] input').focus();
            if (!quote.paymentMethod()) {
                errorProcessor.process({
                    message: $t('Please select a payment method.'),
                });
                return false;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: no, I have this error: caught TypeError: quote.isPaymentError is not a function

Comment: Check My Updated Code.

Comment: No, not work. It go to the checkout success page

Comment: caught ReferenceError: errorProcessor is not defined

Comment: I think this is a kind of dependency issue . check my updated code

Comment: Yes, I added too like your code, but now it do a redirect to cart page when i complete the order on checkout

Comment: The code may be triggering an error that's causing the redirect. Try this updated one.

Answer (score 0):

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList'
], function ($, $t, quote, messageList) {
    'use strict';

    return function () {
        try {                
            if ($('div[name="shippingAddress.custom_attributes.sdi"] input').val() === "") {
                alert($t("Insert SDI field to have elettronic invoice!"));
                $('div[name="shippingAddress.custom_attributes.sdi"] input').focus();
                messageList.addErrorMessage({
                        message: $t('Insert SDI billing address field.')
                });
                return false;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };
});
```

in this way I receive error message correctly, but it redirect to cart page.
I think that the redirection is causing by **return false** statement